# Чем в C#(.NET) можно побитно читать файл и записывать?

Tags: .net, c#

Чем в C#(.NET) можно побитно читать файл и записывать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это шутка такая? Стандартно все работает с байтами. Хотите биты извольте сами на них разбирать. Кстати говоря, в файловой системе минимальный блок обмена - кластер, т.е. несколько физ. секторов, а физический сектор носителя информации обычно 512 байт. А к чему я это веду? А к тому что даже побайтовое чтение до какой-то степени является фикцией.

А еще есть библиотека [BitStream](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/bitstream.aspx). Она вполне подходит на первый взгляд

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.